# node.js express route.get() error

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am using express-generator and installed the dependencies, everything else is as is, except this app.js file I've updated and posted here.

I'm getting the error when running npm start. I've posted the error and app.js file. It's probably something basic, I'm a newb. Thanks so much.

**Error message**

```
    ryan@\Ryan:~/Desktop/node/frameworks/expressapi$ npm start

> expressapi@0.0.0 start /home/ryan/Desktop/node/frameworks/expressapi
> node ./bin/www


/home/ryan/Desktop/node/frameworks/expressapi/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:196
        throw new Error(msg);
              ^
Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.(anonymous function) [as get] (/home/ryan/Desktop/node/frameworks/expressapi/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:196:15)
    at EventEmitter.app.(anonymous function) [as get] (/home/ryan/Desktop/node/frameworks/expressapi/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:481:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ryan/Desktop/node/frameworks/expressapi/app.js:45:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ryan/Desktop/node/frameworks/expressapi/bin/www:7:11)
npm ERR! weird error 8
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

**Server code**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var products = [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'watch',
      description: 'tell time with this amazing watch',
      price: 30.00
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'sandals',
      description: 'walk in comfort with these sansdals',
      price: 10.00
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'watch',
      description: 'protect your eyes!',
      price: 25.00
    }
];

app.get('/', routes.index);

app.get('/products', function(req, res) {
  res.json(products);
});

app.get('/products/:id', function(req, res) {
  if (req.params.id > (products.length - 1) || req.params.id < 0) {
    res.statusCode = 404;
    res.end('NotFound');
  }
  res.json(products[req.params.id]);
});

app.post('/products', function(req, res) {
  if (typeof req.body.name === 'undefined') {
    res.statusCode = 400;
    res.end('a product name is required');
  }
  products.push(req.body);
  res.send(req.body);
});

app.put('/products/:id', function(req, res) {
  if (req.params.id > (products.length - 1) || req.params.id < 0) {
    res.satusCode = 404;
    res.end('not found');
  }
  products[req.params.id] = req.body;
  res.send(req.body);
});

app.delete('/products/:id', function(req, res) {
  if (req.params.id > (products.length - 1) || req.params.id < 0) {
    res.statusCode = 400;
    res.end('not found for that id');
  }
  products.splice(req.params.id, 1);
  res.json(products);
});
```

if i delete line 45 like some have recommended i get the error

```
ryan@\Ryan:~/Desktop/node/frameworks/expressapi$ npm start

> expressapi@0.0.0 start /home/ryan/Desktop/node/frameworks/expressapi
> node ./bin/www


/home/ryan/Desktop/node/frameworks/expressapi/bin/www:16
app.set('port', port);
    ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'set'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ryan/Desktop/node/frameworks/expressapi/bin/www:16:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
npm ERR! weird error 8
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Please share `./bin/www` file.

Comment: i dont see a www file under computer/bin for some reason. probably looking in wrong spot though. sleep, sync, true, touch etc

Comment: no, it will be in the bin directory which shares the same directory as your app.js file. `ls ./bin` not `ls /bin`

Comment: k just made a new thread and will include this file, cmon over , thx! node.js express generator app not responding

Answer (score 1):

This error tells me that you're not passing in a proper express middleware function: `at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ryan/Desktop/node/frameworks/expressapi/app.js:45:5)`

I pasted your code into a text editor and I got this line of code for `45:5`:
`app.get('/', routes.index);`

My guess is that you've deleted the file for routes.index (`var routes = require('./routes/index');`)

Delete this line of code on 45:5 and see if you succeed/get a different error message.

FYI - You have a lot of spelling mistakes that may lead to issues like line 70: `res.satusCode = 404;` has statusCode misspelled, but that's not your current issue, I believe.

Comment: deleted line 45 completely. now i get /home/ryan/Desktop/node/frameworks/expressapi/bin/www:16
app.set('port', port);
    ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'set' and i did correct that typo

Comment: You need to share your `/bin/www` file. Also, are you calling `module.exports = app` in app.js?

Comment: You may want to create a new question as this is a new issue, but it looks like I was right about the first problem.

Comment: k making new thread. ive jsut about gotten this. now just get 404 error after adding module.exports = app give me 5 minutes ill have new post up

Comment: make that a few more minutes since i cant post quick, but the problem i have after adding module.exports = app; is now im not getting a response so maybe theres a typo somewhere > expressapi@0.0.0 start /home/ryan/Desktop/node/frameworks/expressapi
> node ./bin/www

curl -X get http://localhost:3000/products

curl -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/products/2

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're requiring `./routes/index`, and then trying to call `routes.index` in `app.get('/')`.  Try only requiring `'./routes'` initially.

Comment: what do you mean mix? i need the direction to be very specific. Ty

Comment: app.get('./routes'); now i get error /home/ryan/Desktop/node/frameworks/expressapi/bin/www:16
app.set('port', port);
    ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'set'

Comment: Change `var routes = require('./routes/index');` to `var routes = require('./routes');`

Comment: k making new thread. ive jsut about gotten this. now just get 404 error after adding module.exports = app give me 5 minutes ill have new post up

Comment: make that a few more minutes since this site wont let me post quick, but the problem i have after adding module.exports = app; is now im not getting a response so maybe theres a typo somewhere > expressapi@0.0.0 start /home/ryan/Desktop/node/frameworks/expressapi
> node ./bin/www

curl -X get http://localhost:3000/products

curl -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/products/2